# Play's built-in form helper is outputing the data type boolean in the HTML

Tags: scala, playframework

Why does my checkbox in my form display so ugly using the built-in form helperin play?

My form looks like:

```
val subscriptionManageForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "token" -> optional(text),
      "unSubscribe" -> boolean
    ) (SubscriptionManageForm.apply)(SubscriptionManageForm.unapply)
  )
```

The result HTML looks like:

```
<dl class=" " id="unSubscribe_field">

    <dt><label for="unSubscribe">unSubscribe</label></dt>

    <dd>
    <input type="checkbox" id="unSubscribe" name="unSubscribe" value="true"  />
    <span></span>
</dd>


        <dd class="info">format.boolean</dd>

</dl>
```

Below is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

My view page looks like this, as you can see I have some commented out HTML where I was trying to use another form of a helper, but it pretty much outputted the exact same HTML as it does now.

```
@helper.checkbox(form("unSubscribe"))
            <!--@helper.input(form("unSubscribe")) { (id, name, value, args) =>-->
                <!--<input type="checkbox" name="@name" id="@id" >-->
            <!--}-->
```

**Why does it output format.boolean** ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `format.boolean` looks like a not translated string? You have several options to fix this.

**Option 1**

To set `format.boolean` edit or create the file `conf/messages` and add `format.boolean=Something else`.

If you dont want to display anything setting `format.boolean` to `format.boolean=` should also work.

For more info: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaI18N

**Option 2**

`@helper.checkbox(form("subscribe"), '_label -> "Confirm:", '_text -> 
"Some text", '_help -> "Something")`

Where `format.boolean` gets replaced with the value of `_help`.

**Option 3**

You have complete control of what play renders if you want to.
To get rid of the `format.boolean` part and not render it at all do the following:

Custom Form View (view/form/forminput.scala.html):

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<div class="field @if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
    <label for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
    @elements.input
    <span class="error">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>
    <!-- The default renders this. To get rid of format.boolean do not include it.  -->
    <!-- <span class="info">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</--span> -->
</div>
```

Custom Form Code (forms/common/SemanticForms.scala):

```
package forms.common
import views.html

object SemanticForms {
  import views.html.helper.FieldConstructor
  implicit val input = FieldConstructor(html.form.forminput.f)
}
```

Now you just need to import your custom form in your view

```
@import forms.common.SemanticForms._
```

This also allows you to change the look and feel of each form!

For more info: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCustomFieldConstructors

Comment: So the issue is that when I do ```@helper.checkbox(form("unSubscribe"))``` it can't find the translation of what?  Confused as I am using the built-in helper and it displays that, what needs to be translated?

Comment: @Blankman I updated my answer to make it more clear what your options are and why you see this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks!  I just find it strange that "out-of-the-box" you would have to do this when it is such a common thing *shrugs*.

Comment: It is indeed!  It is confusing and it takes time to figure out why.